# Find the limit on distribution of $(Y_n)_{n\in N}$

Tags: probability

I have no idea what I should for this question. It would be great if someone can help me.

Let $(X_n)_{n\in N}$ a sequence of random variables taking values in $[1,\infty)$, such that for each $n \in N$, $X_{n}$ has a Pareto distribution of parameter $n$, with FDA:
$$F_{n}(x)=1-\frac{1}{X_{n}}$$
$$x\geq 1$$

Find the limit on distribution of $(Y_{n})_{n \in N}$, given by $Y_{n}=nX_{n}-n$.

Now I have to:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} F_{n}(x)=1$$

But I don't know how to continue.
I would appreciate your answers.

Definition Pareto Distribution:
A random variable $X$ is said to follow a Pareto Distribution of parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $P(\alpha, \beta)$, if its density function is give by the expression:
$$f(x):=
\left\{
      \begin{array}{11}
            \frac{\beta\alpha^\beta}{x^{\beta+1}} & \mbox{if} x\leq c \\
             0 &\mbox i.a.c.
       \end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "Pareto distribution of parameter $n$"? To my knowledge the Pareto distribution is usually characterized by two parameters.

Comment: @Math1000 We never saw that in class and I was looking in a books and that's just what yoy say, with 2 parameters. :(

Comment: Could you include the book's definition, then?

Comment: @Math1000 I already wrote it.